I am not able to pre populate the input fields in my form. Can anyone help me?
I have just started learning mern and i making a simple app where i have to add items into a menu , update and delete them. for updating i want to pre populate the input field with the item data.
I have been sitting on this issue for a lot of time but i am not able to find a solution. I have set the value attribute of for each input but still i dont see any info in the input field.
React code
menuItems.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import edit from "/edit.png";
import rupee from "../utils/currencyFormatter.jsx";
import api from "../api/api.jsx";
import { capitalize } from "../utils/capitalize.jsx";
import available from "/available.png";
import notavailable from "/notavailable.png";
import deleteImg from "/delete.png";
import EditItem from "./editItem.jsx";

const menuItems = ({ category }) => {
    const [editForm, setEditForm] = useState(false);
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const getItems = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await api.get("/menu");
                setItems(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        };
        getItems();
    }, []);
    const [idi, setId] = useState(0);
    return (
        <ol>
            {editForm && (
                <EditItem
                    isVisible={editForm}
                    setIsVisible={setEditForm}
                    category={category}
                    id={idi}
                />
            )}
            {items.map((i, index) => (
                <li
                    key={i._id}
                    className="grid grid-cols-6 text-[1.5vw] p-3 transition-all duration-100 hover:bg-orange-400 rounded-md"
                >
                    {index + 1}
                    <p className=" flex flex-col justify-center font-semibold">
                        {capitalize(i.item)}
                        <span className="font-thin text-[1.3vw]">
                            {i.description}
                        </span>
                    </p>
                    <span>{rupee.format(i.price)}</span>
                    <span>
                        {i.availability ? (
                            <img
                                src={available}
                                alt="Available"
                                className=" h-8 w-8"
                            />
                        ) : (
                            <img
                                src={notavailable}
                                alt="Not Available"
                                className=" h-8 w-8"
                            />
                        )}
                    </span>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => {
                            setEditForm(true);
                            setId(i._id);
                        }}
                    >
                        <img src={edit} alt="edit" className="h-10 w-10" />
                    </button>
                    <button>
                        <img
                            src={deleteImg}
                            alt="delete"
                            className=" h-10 w-10"
                        />
                    </button>
                </li>
            ))}
        </ol>
    );
};

export default menuItems;


editItem.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import axios from "../api/api.jsx";

const editItem = ({ isVisible, setIsVisible, category, id }) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        const getItems = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`/menu/${id}`);
                setFormData(response.data);
                
                console.log("updated formData:", formData);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                setFormData({});
            }
        };
        getItems();
    }, [id]);
    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            console.log(formData.category);
            const response = await axios.put(`/menu/${id}`, formData);
            console.log(response.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
        }
        setIsVisible(!isVisible);
    };
    if (!isVisible) return null;
    return (
        <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25 backdrop-blur-sm flex justify-center items-center">
            <div className="w-[50%] flex flex-col">
                <div className="bg-white p-2 rounded">
                    <h2 className="mb-4 text-2xl text-center font-bold text-gray-900">
                        Add a new product
                    </h2>
                    <form
                        action="post"
                        className=" p-4"
                        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                    >
                        <div className="grid gap-4 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-6">
                            <div className="sm:col-span-2">
                                <label
                                    htmlFor="item"
                                    className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-90"
                                >
                                    Item Name
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    name="item"
                                    id="item"
                                    className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 "
                                    placeholder="Type Item name"
                                    required
                                    value={formData.item}
                                    onChange={(event) => {
                                        setFormData({
                                            ...formData,
                                            item: event.target.value,
                                        });
                                        console.log(
                                            "Item input value:",
                                            event.target.value
                                        );
                                    }}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="w-full">
                                <label
                                    htmlFor="price"
                                    className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-90"
                                >
                                    Price
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="number"
                                    name="price"
                                    id="price"
                                    className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-600 focus:border-primary-600 block w-full p-2.5 "
                                    required
                                    placeholder="Add the price"
                                    value={formData.price}
                                    onChange={(event) =>
                                        setFormData({
                                            ...formData,
                                            price: event.target.value,
                                        })
                                    }
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <label
                                    htmlFor="category"
                                    className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-90"
                                >
                                    Category
                                </label>
                                <select
                                    id="category"
                                    className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full p-2.5 "
                                    value={formData.category}
                                    onChange={(event) => {
                                        setFormData({
                                            ...formData,
                                            category: event.target.value,
                                        });
                                    }}
                                >
                                    <option>Select category</option>
                                    {category.map((c) => (
                                        <option key={c._id} value={c._id}>
                                            {c.name}
                                        </option>
                                    ))}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex items-center">
                                <label
                                    htmlFor="availability"
                                    className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-90 mr-5"
                                >
                                    Availability
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="checkbox"
                                    name="avaialability"
                                    id="availability"
                                    value={formData.availability}
                                    onChange={(event) => {
                                        if (event.target.checked) {
                                            setFormData({
                                                ...formData,
                                                availability: true,
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }}
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="flex gap-4 items-center">
                                <label
                                    htmlFor="veg"
                                    className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-90"
                                >
                                    Veg
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="veg_or_nonveg"
                                    value="veg"
                                    id="veg"
                                    onChange={(event) =>
                                        setFormData({
                                            ...formData,
                                            veg_or_nonveg: event.target.value,
                                        })
                                    }
                                />
                                <label
                                    htmlFor="nonveg"
                                    className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-90"
                                >
                                    Non Veg
                                </label>
                                <input
                                    type="radio"
                                    name="veg_or_nonveg"
                                    value="non-veg"
                                    id="nonveg"
                                    onChange={(event) =>
                                        setFormData({
                                            ...formData,
                                            veg_or_nonveg: event.target.value,
                                        })
                                    }
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="sm:col-span-2">
                                <label
                                    htmlFor="description"
                                    className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-90"
                                >
                                    Description
                                </label>
                                <textarea
                                    id="description"
                                    rows="8"
                                    className="block p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300 focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 "
                                    placeholder="Item Description"
                                    value={formData.description}
                                    onChange={(event) =>
                                        setFormData({
                                            ...formData,
                                            description: event.target.value,
                                        })
                                    }
                                ></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="flex">
                            <button
                                type="submit"
                                className="flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 mt-2 text-sm font-medium text-center rounded-lg focus:ring-4 focus:ring-primary-200"
                            >
                                Edit product
                            </button>
                            <button
                                className=" flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 mt-2 text-sm font-medium text-center rounded-lg text-red-600  focus:ring-4 focus:ring-primary-200"
                                onClick={() => {
                                    setIsVisible(!isVisible);
                                }}
                            >
                                Cancel
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default editItem;

Express Code
controllers
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { menuModel } from "../models/menuModel.js";

export const getMenuItems = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const menuItems = await menuModel.find();
        res.status(200).json(menuItems);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
        console.log(err);
    }
};

export const getOneItem = async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    try {
        const item = await menuModel.find({ _id: id });
        res.status(200).json(item);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: err.message });
    }
};

export const addMenuItems = async (req, res) => {
    const item = req.body;
    const newItem = new menuModel(item);
    try {
        await newItem.save();
        res.status(201).json(newItem);
        console.log(newItem);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(409).json({ message: err.message });
    }
};

export const updateMenuItmes = async (req, res) => {
    const { id: _id } = req.params;
    const updatedData = req.body;
    try {
        if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(_id))
            return res.status(404).send("no item with that id exists");
        const updates = await menuModel.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, updatedData, {
            new: true,
        });
        res.status(200).json(updates);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(409).json({ message: err.message });
    }
};

// export const deleteItems = async (req,res) =>{
// }


menuModel.jsx - contains the model of the menu
import { Decimal128 } from "mongodb";
import mongoose, { model } from "mongoose";
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const menuSchema = new Schema({
    item: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0.0,
    },
    availability: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: true,
    },
    veg_or_nonveg: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ["Veg", "Non-Veg", "veg", "non-veg"],
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
    },
    category: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "categoryModel",
        },
    ],
});

export const menuModel = new model('menuModel', menuSchema);

i have added value attribute as you can see here but i find no pre populated data
Can anyone help me with the issue.
here is the github repo link:

Try console.log to see what data is available where. That way you can narrow down what line is failing to give you the expected result.

actually i have tried that to see if the data is coming correctly or no, and i see no problem.
i console logged the form data and i notice that formdata is not assigned with the variable in the first go
it is actually assigned after the 4th or 5th console log.
could that be the issue? if so could you tell how to solve it

can you show us exactly what response.data looks like from your getItems call?

[
{
"_id": "6672bd509e4b7d8dbb734a0a",
"item": "vade ",
"price": 20,
"availability": true,
"veg_or_nonveg": "veg",
"description": "idli vade",
"category": [
"6670746a33202ee19c2488a7"
],
"__v": 0
}
]

sorry, i meant what is response.data from your EditItem getItems call, not your MenuItems getItems call?  if this is the data from EditItem, this might be a problem, since your form expects a single object and that is an array.

this is the ediItems getItem call.
can i fix that by using [0]??

@sparkJ thank you so much
this actually started filling the form with data but a slight issue is
the data is getting populated into the form after a delay.
do you have any idea why??

@sparkJ this issue occurs only when width of the screen is less

Looks like you have a getItems() call in the editItem component, so it fetches the same data again that you already had when displaying without edit - assuming /menu returns same data for all elements as /menu/id does for a single one. The delay might come from there as you await the response from the db.
Try passing the values as props to the edit component to not fetch it twice. When you have multiple menu items you can map through the array and pass the props to each individual item component. and have you tried using defaultValue instead of value to populate the input fields?

Ok I will try that, but why the delay only when the screen width is small??

Have you checked with the console log if it has to do with the async request, even on small screen? UseEffect runs after the page has been rendered, so you will have a few empty console logs as you described. Is the small screen another device or just smaller window?

yes i do have empty console logs but that's there even on the large screen

the problem on small screen still there? And are the logs different on small screen?

no no now it got solved after sending the items as props. Thank you for your help. I was just asking for info.
